# Javascript error yet the code still works

Tags: javascript

Ok I am really confused. Right now I am working on getting a datagrid to focus on a cell by selecting a point on a map. Below is the javascript that controls the election. I added `cell.elements.focus()` and it DOES focus on the cell I want it to but it also gives me an error at the same time saying "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'element' is null or not an object" Any idea why it would give me an error but still work? Is there a way I can get rid of this error?

```
function selectRowByID(sIDField, sID) {
var bSelectionFound = false;
var grid = igtbl_getGridById(_gridID);
if (grid != null) {
    var rows = grid.Rows;
    for (var x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
        var row = rows.getRow(x);
        var cell = row.getCellFromKey(sIDField);
        if (cell != null) {
            cell.scrollToView(true);
            if (cell.getValue() == sID) {
                row.setSelected(true);
                cell.element.focus();
                bSelectionFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
return bSelectionFound;
```

Comment: Did you try doing `if(cell.element) cell.element.focus();` Just for caution?

Comment: IF you comment out //cell.element.focus(); ? Sure setSelected isnt doing it?

Comment: Why would you do:


                cell.element.focus();

Instead of:


                cell.focus();

Comment: Well I tried cell.focus() before and the focus() object is not part of cell but it is part of cell.element. This is the error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says 'element' is not set. Try skipping the .element in this sentence

```
cell.element.focus();
```

so it becomes

```
cell.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but try replacing

`cell.element.focus();`

with

```
if (cell.element) cell.element.focus();
```

that might get rid of the error.

Comment: cell.focus() gives me this error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method", also if I do if(cell.element) it would always skip cell.element.focus(). The biggest issue I have is cell.element.focus() WORKS while giving an error at the same time.

Comment: debugger it just saying that cell is an Object.

Comment: it doesn't list the methods that are on cell?

Comment: from what I am seeing it seems a lot of the methods are all custom events. I will have to try and find these because I can't find them at all. The Methods are all in this file but its only a dynamic file ig_WebGrid_dom.js. It is no one in my project that I can edit...